# Duplicate symbol at link time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Just as background, there are no compile-time errors or warnings in the subject project "Project".

There are numerous occurrences of using the same instance variable name in two (or more classes).  In the following, I'll use the variable name "index" as an example.  It appears as an instance variable in class1 and class2.  The variable has different but similar meanings in both classes, hence the use of the common term.

I define index in the header file for both class1 and class2, for example:

@interface class1 : NSObject
{
int index;
}
...

Repeat for class2.

When I build the project, Xcode reports:

Duplicate symbol _index in /Project/build/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.build/Objects-normal/i386/class1.o and /Project/build/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.build/Objects-normal/i386/class2.o

Changing the occurrences of "index" to "indexnotverycommon", reports the same error with the new name.

Changing the occurrences to "index1" and "index2" respectively gets rid of the error.  Xcode then reports the next duplicate it finds during linking, and so on, and so on.

I can continue the renaming process although I'd rather not, as I'm concerned that there is a more pathological underlying issue.

Any advice or question is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the complete text of your classes (removing un-necessary code until it just fails).  Personally I think you should check very closely to see if you have actually declared then both as @interface class1.

Answer (score 2):

index is a also a C function and thus a very unfortunate name in Objective-C.
This [article](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-05/the-peril-of-the-index-function) describes why it's not a good idea to use index as a name.

I'm not sure why you get duplicate symbols though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the Xcode find-in-project feature.  Thanks for the advice about index.

Comment: Was this because you accidentally had an #import of a .m file where you meant the .h?

Comment: cdespinosa, wish I could upvote this, I ran out of ideas and that was the solution. Thank you. Edit: Turns out I can upvote this :)

Answer (score 0):

The tip to check for an `#import "Xxx.m"` instead of the correct .h worked.

A quick workspace wide search for `"Xxx.m"` spotted the error in the `include` which was causing the link error.

Answer (score 0):

don't #include or #import .m files. Just add those .m files into the Target | Build Phases. Don't add .h files into build phases, but #import .h files wherever you need those functions.

The compiler knows that it's just a header file "for information only" and that the bodies of the functions will be available when it will compile the .m files and put them all into 1 executable

The header file contains only forward declarations. Compiler knows that the body is either defined in another file or is in a lib linked to the project